# ReactJS - add delete buttons to items displayed with map()

Tags: reactjs

I have this player, which uses `map()` to display all items, like so:

```
 class Player extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        youtube_urls:[],
        artists:[],
        loadedVideosCount: 0,
        currentPlayingIndex: -1, 
    };
  };

  render(){
    const { select } = this.props
    const { artists, youtube_urls, loadedVideosCount, currentPlayingIndex  } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">{ this.Capitalize(select) } playlist</font></h1>
          <div className="Line" />
        </div>

        { 
            artists.map((artist, index) => {
              return (
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <div key={artist}>
                      <ul>
                        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Artist: </font></strong><strong><font color="#6f4e37" size='2'>{ artist }</font></strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ReactPlayer 
                      url={ audio }
                      controls
                      width='50'
                      height='150'
                      onLoaded={() =>
                      this.setState(currentState => ({
                          loadedVideosCount: loadedVideosCount + 1,
                          currentPlayingIndex:
                            loadedVideosCount + 1 === youtube_urls.length ? 0 : -1,
                        }))
                      }
                      onEnded={() =>
                      this.setState(currentState => ({
                          currentPlayingIndex: currentPlayingIndex + 1,
                        }))
                      }
                      playing={index === currentPlayingIndex}
                    />
                    <div className="Line" />
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              )
            })
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way of adding a 'delete' button for each item as well?

Comment: Why don't you just add the button in the `.map()` function result for each element? I will write an answer with example code.

Comment: please do so...

Comment: I did. Tell me if this is the desired effect, if not, tell me what's the problem, so I can modify it and help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that artists is an array of strings by the code you presented. Simply implement a function that deletes this artist from the state, using the Array.filter() function and save it into the state. Then add a button for each record that calls this function.

```
class Player extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        youtube_urls:[],
        artists:[],
        loadedVideosCount: 0,
        currentPlayingIndex: -1, 
    };
  };

  render(){
    const { select } = this.props
    const { artists, youtube_urls, loadedVideosCount, currentPlayingIndex  } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">{ this.Capitalize(select) } playlist</font></h1>
          <div className="Line" />
        </div>

        { 
            artists.map((artist, index) => {
              return (
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <div key={artist}>
                      <ul>
                        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Artist: </font></strong><strong><font color="#6f4e37" size='2'>{ artist }</font></strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ReactPlayer 
                      url={ audio }
                      controls
                      width='50'
                      height='150'
                      onLoaded={() =>
                      this.setState(currentState => ({
                          loadedVideosCount: loadedVideosCount + 1,
                          currentPlayingIndex:
                            loadedVideosCount + 1 === youtube_urls.length ? 0 : -1,
                        }))
                      }
                      onEnded={() =>
                      this.setState(currentState => ({
                          currentPlayingIndex: currentPlayingIndex + 1,
                        }))
                      }
                      playing={index === currentPlayingIndex}
                    />
                    <div className="Line" />
                    <span onClick={() => {this.deleteItem(artist)}}>Delete artist</span>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              )
            })
          }
      </div>
    )
  }

  deleteItem = artistToDelete => {
      let { artists } = this.state;
      let filteredArtists = artists.filter(artist => artist !== artistToDelete);
      this.setState({
          artists: filteredArtists
      })
  }
}
```

P.S. If each artist is not a string, but an object, you will have to modify the filter function, by addding the condition that the array must be filtered by.

**EDIT: I made a mistake in the filter function, the === sign, must be changed with !==.**

Comment: `deleteItem` must be put inside `render()`?

Comment: I put it before and all items were deleted.

Comment: No, it stays outside of render function, but yet inside of the class.

Comment: Check the edit I made earlier, change the === sign with !==

Comment: Oh, all items were deleted because it was a duplicate item....